# Android eclipse | Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a real problem with my first **Android** application on **eclipse**.

As in every tutorial, i've installed the compatible **Android sdk** (**adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917**) on my windows 8. and dowloaded all the updates.

I've already had **eclipse** installed, i've just downloaded the **adt plugin**

Then i created an **Android Application project** on **android 2.2**, and when i run the project i get this :

```
[2013-11-07 00:05:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-11-07 00:05:34 - test] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

i googled the error msg and found a lot of solutions but nothing of this solution worked:

- I've changed the eclipse.ini file
- I've cleared the project to many times
- I've uninstaled and reinstalled the eclipse and the sdk to many times
- I've tried to remove all the jars(i found that the cause may be the some duplicated jars).
- I've changed the java build path on the proect proprietes, i uncheked
  Android Private Libraires, and Android Dependecies and cheked Android 2.2 + test/src and test/gen that cant be uncheked

I'm stuck here 3 days by now :/ i just wana create my first hello world app